# How do I pass parameters when running the code?

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn more about Python in my spare time.  I am a .net developer.  I have downloaded a simple open source project, which is run as follows:

```
python3.6 ./project/main.py -c config.json
```

I have downloaded vscode and I can now debug the project, however after clicking 'Start debugging' in  vs code; the command that is generated by the VS Code terminal misses the end i.e. `-c config.json`

How can i add the command line argument. As a .net developer i would just open visual studio on a windows pc, right click on the project and select properties and then add the arguments to the appropriate text box.  i have spent several hours googling this and the only way to do it appears to be to create a launch.json file as described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging.  I also looked here: [Running a Python program with arguments from within the Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036942/running-a-python-program-with-arguments-from-within-the-visual-studio-code).  Dons' answer says arguments are specified like this:

```
"args":["arg1", "arg2"]
```

My argument is more like a key value pair rather than a single argument.

Please note that I am opening the project using file/open folder, so there is no project file like there is with a .net solution visual Studio.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need `"args":["./project/main.py", "-c", "config.json"]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code: How debug Python script with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244223/visual-studio-code-how-debug-python-script-with-arguments) `launch.json` docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging